# Error when count() was assign to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Hi i tried get a table count in php/mysql assignment, but it gives an error called

> Resource id #5

My code

```
$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%'");

echo($table_count);
```

can anybody help on this matter

Comment: You need to fetch the record to assign to a variable. Check for mysql_fetch_row , mysql_fetch_assoc etc.

Comment: use a loop over result or extract result from query result mysql_fetch_assoc()

Comment: You don't get an error, but a resource with the id 5. Use something likee [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to fetch the resource

Comment: +1 for asking a question which many php beginners don't know! I too wasted my time solving this kind of errors!!Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, do not use `mysql_*` functions, becuase they are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

Second: `mysql_query` gives you back a resource. You need to fetch the row(s) from that with `mysql_fetch_assoc` function.

So you need something like this:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
var_dump($row["cnt"]);
```

Comment: Hi thank you for all your answers but now it returns "Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 13 ) " which is correct, but isnt there a way i could get only "13" as the result

Comment: `$row["cnt"]` will gives you back 13, not `Array` This is how the associative arrays works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this format for getting count(column):-

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) from table name where condition" ;  //your mysql query inside paranthesis
mysql_select_db(''); //your database name inside quotes

$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval,MYSQL_BOTH); 

echo $row[0]; // your result
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @user3584871 According to my knowledge the error is because you are trying to print the array but not the array[0] result.Hence the error "Resource id #5" will come.

Comment: This will gives you back: `Array`

Comment: Hi thank you for all your answers but now it returns "Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 13 ) " which is correct, but isnt there a way i could get only "13" as the result

Comment: @lolka_bolka :- Ya! Sorry I thought I have added row[0]! Thanks for the concern! Try to remove the comment I have edited the answer!!

Answer (score -1):

Please note, mysql_* functions have been deprecated and will be removed in future. It is strongly advised to use PDO or mysqli extension.

`$table_count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mydb' AND table_name LIKE 'table_%'");

echo(mysql_num_rows($table_count));`

Comment: This is bad. It will always gives you back 1, because OP selects `COUNT(*)` not rows.

Comment: Hi thank you for all your answers but now it returns "Array ( [COUNT(*)] => 13 ) " which is correct, but isnt there a way i could get only "13" as the result